# Shader class in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Im am currently wrapping all OpenGL ressources (which are simply a GLuint) into classes that own and manage the deletion of them, to make it possible to use OpenGL in an object oriented fassion. Since these classes manage a ressource that get's destroyed in their destructor i know the rule of five is something to think about. This is how my Shader classes look like:

Shader.h :

```
#pragma once

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <string>

class Shader
{
public:

    Shader(GLuint type, const std::string& shaderPath);
    virtual ~Shader();

    Shader(const Shader& s) = delete;
    Shader& operator = (const Shader& s) = delete;

    Shader(Shader&&) = default;
    Shader& operator = (Shader&&) = default;

private:

    /*
        The Shader objects are passed to the constructor  
        of ShaderProgram that compiles the glShaderProgram -> needs id 
    */
    friend class ShaderProgram; // 

    GLuint id = 0;
};

class FragmentShader : public Shader
{
public:

    FragmentShader(const std::string& shaderPath) : Shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderPath) {};
};

class VertexShader : public Shader
{
public:

    VertexShader(const std::string& shaderPath) : Shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, shaderPath) {};
};
```

Shader.cpp :

```
Shader::Shader(GLuint type, const std::string& shaderPath)
{
    std::ifstream fstram;
    std::stringstream sstream;

    fstram.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit); 

    fstram.open(shaderPath);    
    sstream << fstram.rdbuf();
    fstram.close(); 

    id = glCreateShader(type);

    auto data = sstream.str();
    const char* dataPtr = data.c_str();

    glShaderSource(id, 1, &dataPtr, NULL);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if(result == 0)
    {
        char infolog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, 1024, NULL, infolog);

        throw std::runtime_error(infolog);
    }
}

Shader::~Shader()
{
    glDeleteShader(id);
}
```

Use them like this:

```
try
{
    VertexShader vs("Path to file");
    FragmentShader fs("Path to file");
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Because i am planning to implement classes for the ofther OpenGL ressources like buffers, textures, etc  in a similar fassion i would like some feedback. Any insight on mistakes that i made or how to improve my code are very appreciated. And do i need to declare move assignment and move constructor in the derived shader classes too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it really necessary to split vertex and fragment shaders into their own type? It causes the type to go from 4 bytes to 16 bytes on a typical 64 bit processor, just for it to store a vtable ptr for the destructor that's never going to do anything different.

They could privately inherit and not have a virtual destructor, but I would rather they just be a single class and let incorrectly assigning shaders to a program be a runtime error. There's already a potential failure point when creating the shader program, and the gl error should alert the client to what went wrong, so it's not introducing a new point of failure.

You can't use the default move functions because they won't zero-out the id, and `glDeleteShader` will be called twice on the same id.

Consider using a factory function to create shaders from file instead of doing file IO in the constructor. It will make it easier to test, and it's also not obvious that this is a blocking function that shouldn't be called on UI threads.

It also makes it more portable to possibly use in a context that doesn't want to use fstreams for doing file IO, for example if you had zipped shaders or hosted them on a cloud it would make more sense to pass in a byte array which is what  `glShaderSource` will expect.

If you're going to use a path constructor, consider std::filesystem::path.